# How can I validate a field based on another field?

Tags: haskell, digestive-functors

I'm trying to have a registration form with fields like `email` and `emailConfirmation`, or `password` and `passwordConfirmation`. Validating `email` and `password` is easy, there are rules and I've written the respective functions.

The other two are harder though. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106964/validation-spanning-multiple-fields) and tried writing my code like this:

The form definition, using Blaze:

```
registrationForm :: (View Html) -> Html
registrationForm view = docTypeHtml $ do
  form ! name "registration" ! method "post" ! action "/register" $ do
    fieldset $ do
      label ! for "password" $ (text "Password")
      inputText "password" view
      errorList "password" view

      br

      label ! for "passwordConfirmation" $ (text "Password Confirmation")
      inputText "passwordConfirmation" view
      errorList "passwordConfirmation" view
```

and the validator:

```
data Password = Password { password :: Text }

validateForm :: Monad m => Form Html m Password
validateForm =
  Password
    <$> "password" .: validatePassword
  where
    validatePassword =
      validate fst' $ (,) <$> ("password"             .: D.text Nothing)
                          <*> ("passwordConfirmation" .: D.text Nothing)
    fst' (p1, p2) | p1 == p2  = Success p1
                  | otherwise = Error "Passwords must match"
```

But whenever I run the server I get a message saying "password is not a field". If I remove the validation and give `password` a simple validation, then it works as expected. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help on the digestive-functors repository. [Thanks cimmanon](https://github.com/jaspervdj/digestive-functors/issues/128)

This is the final code, note field name is now "password.p1"/"password.p2" instead of just password/passwordConfirmation.

```
registrationForm :: (View Html) -> Html
registrationForm view = docTypeHtml $ do
  form ! name "registration" ! method "post" ! action "/register" $ do
    fieldset $ do
      inputText "password.p1" view
      br
      inputText "password.p2" view
      errorList "password" view
data Password = Password { password :: Text }
```

validator is the same, except for new names:

```
validateForm :: Monad m => Form Html m Password
validateForm =
  Password
    <$> "password" .: validatePassword
  where
    validatePassword =
      validate fst' $ (,) <$> ("p1" .: D.text Nothing)
                          <*> ("p2" .: D.text Nothing)
    fst' (p1, p2) | p1 == p2  = Success p1
                  | otherwise = Error "Passwords must match"
```